# Chern class of holomorphic symplectic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ a complex surface and $\omega\in H^0(\Omega_M^2,M)$ a non degenerate holomomorphic form.
I've read somewhere (without proof), that then the first chern class of the symplecitc manifold $(M,Re~ \omega)$ vanishes.

Why is this true? As far as I know, the Chern class of $(M, Re~ \omega)$ is the chern class of any complex vector bundle with almost complex structure compatible with $Re ~\omega$. I would suspect that the original complex structure is of this kind. But doing a local calculation, this seems to be only correct up to a sign.

---

Update: Now posted on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323746/symplectic-chern-class-of-holomorphic-symplectic-manifold?noredirect=1#comment808000_323746)

EDIT: (The calculation)
We need that $Re ~\omega(Ju,Jv)=Re~\omega(u,v)$ for all tangent vectors $u,v$. By linearity of $\omega$ it suffices to check this for a basis of each tangent space. So I check this for $\frac \partial {\partial z_i}$ and $\frac \partial {\partial \bar z_i}$.
As $\omega$ is of type $(2,0)$, it is locally of the form $\sum a_{kl}~dz_k\wedge dz_l$.
Hence the only interesting case to check is
$\omega(\frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial z_j})$.
We have
$$\omega(J \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, J \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})
= \omega(i \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, i \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})
=-\omega( \frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial  z_j}), $$
$$\bar\omega(J \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, J \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})= \omega(i \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, i \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})=-\bar\omega( \frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})$$ 
and hence
$$Re ~\omega(J \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, J \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})
=\frac 1 2[\omega(J \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, J \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})+\bar \omega(J \frac \partial {\partial z_i}, J \frac \partial {\partial  z_j})]
=-\frac 1 2[\omega( \frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial z_j})+\omega( \frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial z_j})]
= -Re~ \omega( \frac \partial {\partial z_i},  \frac \partial {\partial  z_j}).$$

Now that I think about it, this just seems to be the proof that Kähler forms are of type $(1,1)$.

Comment: Note that $\omega$ gives you a trivialization of the canonical bundle, and so $c_1$ of the canonical bundle, hence the holomorphic cotangent bundle, hence the holomorphic tangent bundle, vanishes; then recall that the ordinary tangent bundle is isomorphic as a complex vector bundle to the holomorphic tangent bundle.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic: Sorry, but this is not clear to me. I get that the chern class of the holomorphic tangent bundle vanishes. I know that thhe holomorphic tangent bundle is isomorphic to the$(1,0)$-part of the complexified real tangent bundle. What do you mean with the "ordinary tangent bundle"? Further, where in your argument does it enter, that we we want to calculate the chern class of a specific symplectic structure on $M$?

Comment: First note that symplectic does not enter since the Chern class only depends on the complex structure (and you’re starting with a complex surface). By “ordinary” tangent bundle I mean the tangent bundle of the underlying smooth manifold (and this has the structure of a complex bundle because of the complex structure).

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic: But why does the complex structure induced by the symplecitc form coincide with the original complex structure?

Comment: I see, sorry for not reading carefully. You said you did a computation to show that the two complex structures coincide “up to sign” though? Can you elaborate on that; maybe then we’ll see how one vanishing Chern class implies the other.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic I included the calculation. But I am more and more convinced that that the sign issue cannot be fixed easily. i.e. that $\omega$ is not compatible with the original complex structure.

Comment: I recently encountered the definition of Chern classes of symplectic manifolds and would also be interested in an answer to this

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @klirk unfrotunately not

Comment: I added a bounty

Comment: @klirk thank you very much. Unfortunately, there still seems to be only few interest in the question =(

Comment: Nobody cared =(